# Enviar un Formulario generado con un [While] mediante POST por Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

tengo un problema al intentar ejecutar un POST por AJAX, si la funcion la necesito tener dentro de un [While] que contiene un [Form] y necesito modificar los [IDs] dinámicos del [Script] y del [Form], ¿Como llamo la función $(document).ready(function(){ si ya no puedo ponerla en el head porque tengo que ponerla dentro del while en el body?¿la quito sin mas?, desde el [Head] funcionaba cuando buscaba un [ID] en el documento, pero en éste caso tengo que buscar todos los [IDs][Submit] que genere el [While] dentro del [Form] y no se como ponerlo para que me ejecute el post :/

Adjunto el principio del While donde contiene el form con sus submits correspendientes:

```
            while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($result5todos, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

                echo "
                <table border='3' id='table-ama' >
                    <tr>
                        <form METHOD='POST' id='".$fila[ID]."_formulario_EditarObjeto' accept-charset='utf-8'>
                        <td align='center' class='tdconsulta permisosweb' id='ID' >  
                        <strong style='color:cyan'>ID:</strong> ".$fila[ID]."
                        ";
                if(($UAPrivilegios == 'Moderador') or ($UAPrivilegios == 'Administrador') or ($UAPrivilegios == 'AdminFull')){ echo "
                        <br>
                        <input TYPE='hidden' readonly='readonly'  value='".$fila[ID]."' name='ID'>

                        <input TYPE='hidden' readonly='readonly'  value='".$fila[Tipo]."' name='EditarObjeto_Tipo_Objeto'>
                        <input TYPE='hidden' readonly='readonly'  value='".$fila[Creado_por]."' name='EditarObjeto_Creado_por'>

                        <INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' onclick='return confirmar2()' id='".$fila[ID]."_btn-EditarObjeto' VALUE='Actualizar' class='boton-azul' >
                        <br>
                ";} 

                if(($UAPrivilegios == 'Administrador') or ($UAPrivilegios == 'AdminFull')){ echo "
                        <br>
                        <input TYPE='hidden' readonly='readonly'  value='".$fila[Nom_Obj]."' name='nom_Objeto'>
                        <input TYPE='hidden' readonly='readonly'  value='".$_SESSION["usuarioactual"]."' name='Eliminar_Usuario'>
                        <INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' onclick='return confirmar2()' id='".$fila[ID]."_btn-EliminarObjeto' VALUE='Eliminar' class='boton-rojo' style='margin-bottom:4px;'>


                ";} echo "

                        </td>
                ";
```

Y aquí adjunto el Código donde se ve que termina el [Form], los scripts y donde termina el [While], también una captura de los [Forms] con los botones que se generan:

Captura: http://prntscr.com/l9henc

```
echo "
            </form> 
        </tr>
    </table>";
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //Formulario Editar Objeto _ Envio Ajax
                        $(document).on('ready',function(){
                            $('#<?php echo $fila[ID]; ?>_btn-EditarObjeto').click(function(){
                                var url = "./ajaxpaginaobjeto/Formulario_EditarObjeto.php";                                      

                                $.ajax({                        
                                type: "POST",                 
                                url: url,                    
                                data: $("#<?php echo $fila[ID]; ?>_formulario_EditarObjeto").serialize(),
                                success: function(data)            
                                {
                                    $('#CrearObjeto_Respuesta').html(data);           
                                }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                        //Formulario EliminarObjeto _ Envio Ajax
                            $(document).on('ready',function(){
                                $('#<?php echo $fila[ID]; ?>_btn-EliminarObjeto').click(function(){
                                    var url = "./ajaxpaginaobjeto/Formulario_EliminarObjeto.php";                                      

                                    $.ajax({                        
                                    type: "POST",                 
                                    url: url,                    
                                    data: $("#<?php echo $fila[ID]; ?>_formulario_EditarObjeto").serialize(),
                                    success: function(data)            
                                    {
                                        $('#CrearObjeto_Respuesta').html(data);           
                                    }
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                </script>
            <?php
            } // Fin del While
        ?>
```

Yo quiero enviar el POST a PHP por AJAX para que se ejecuten los formularios al instante sin tener que recargar la pantalla, pero si no logro que funcione no tendre mas remedio que enviar el formulario de forma estandar.

Un Saludo

Comment: No es necesario crear una función js para cada columna si al final realizas lo mismo solo cambiando el ID, pon tu código también de la tabla  y el while completo ya que pones //fin del while pero no veo el inicio

Comment: Podrias usar una clase en lugar de ids.  De esa forma no necesitarias poner el script dentro del while.  Ademas puedes usar `$(document).ready(function() {` en lugar de `$(document).on('ready', function() {`

Comment: Sr1871 el while es bastante largo, he corregido el post añadiendo aunque sea el principio del while que contiene el inicio del form con los submit distintos, ya se que estoy creando una funcion para cada js, pero es que no se como hacerlo para que en la funcion cambie el id segun el id que ejecute el while en ese momento

Comment: alanfcm una clase? y como implemento una clase que me localice los distintos submit dentro de ese form en el script?

Comment: Si le pongo una clase en    $('#btn-EditarObjeto').click(function(){  al clicar el submit ¿cojería los valores del form? si es así, vuelvo a lo mismo, ¿como sabe sobre que form tiene que actuar si se genera 1 form por cada while? tendria que ponerle un id o un class diferente a cada form para que lo detecte

Answer (score 1):

he utilizado éste ejemplo y parece que funciona.

Lo comparto para el que le sirva y tambien me gustaria saber si esta bien formulado o debo cambiar algo para que quede bien estructurado el código:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','.btn-EliminarObjeto2',function () {

            // capture input and select value by traversing up into parent(tr),
            // then find element [input, select]
            // this traversing method depend on your table structure
            var Nombre_Objeto = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=nom_Objeto]').val(),
                Nombre_Usuario = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=Eliminar_Usuario]').val();

            $.ajax({                  
            type: "POST", 
            url: "./ajaxpaginaobjeto/Formulario_EliminarObjeto.php",
            data: {
                ID               : $(this).val(),
                nom_Objeto       : Nombre_Objeto,
                Eliminar_Usuario : Nombre_Usuario,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#CrearObjeto_Respuesta2').html(data);   
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <?php
        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($result6todos, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input TYPE='hidden' readonly='readonly'  value='".$fila[Nom_Obj]."' name='nom_Objeto'>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input TYPE='hidden' readonly='readonly'  value='".$_SESSION["usuarioactual"]."' name='Eliminar_Usuario'>
                        <button VALUE='".$fila[ID]."' class='btn-EliminarObjeto2' >Eliminar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    ?>

</body>
```